# adding second function to an exiting function app under the same resource group

Tags: azure-functions

[image]I created an azure app, under which there is a function that has been deployed and running using the suggested yaml structure provided by Microsoft for CI-CD...

When I try to deploy a second function to the same app it overrides the existing function and not add to the list. Any guidance on how to achieve this ?

```
name: Deploy Python project to Azure Function App

on:
  [push]

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: 'your-app-name'   # set this to your function app name on Azure
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'       # set this to the path to your function app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.9'                     # set this to the python version to use (e.g. '3.6', '3.7', '3.8')

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Python ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Pip'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt --target=".python_packages/lib/site-packages"
        popd

    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
        enable-oryx-build: true
```

Comment: Can you show something else to help us along? Screenshots? The YAML? Anything?!?

Comment: The deployed package overwrites the existing package like the message says. You need to deploy a package containing all the functions you want.

Answer (score 0):

**The dir structure worked for me**

```
project-root/
|-- .github/
|   |-- workflows/
|       |-- azure-deploy.yml  # This is a sample name for the GitHub Actions CI/CD file
|-- function1/
|   |-- host.json
|   |-- function.json
|   |-- code-files...
|-- function2/
|   |-- host.json
|   |-- function.json
|   |-- code-files...
|-- .gitignore
|-- README.md
```